Why is ROS1 Message Generation Slow in Python?
I hit a performance issue when trying to use a custom message type in ROS 1 Noetic in Python. My custom message was defined like this:
# Grasp.msg
Header header
geometry_msgs/Pose pose
float32 confidence
float32 width

And an array of these messages was defined like this:
# Grasps.msg
Header header
Grasp[] grasps

Creating ~10k of these messages was taking around 0.25 seconds.
When I went to profile my code, I realized that the majority of the time (>80%) was spent creating the empty message. If I write an equivalent class/dataclass to store my message data, the overhead is not nearly this high (~20% spent creating the class) and the speed is several times faster.
Other message types (non-custom) take similarly long to generate:
Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
    23                                           def create_and_fill_msg():
    24     10001    1039578.0    103.9      4.4      for _ in range(10000):
    25     10000   12915914.0   1291.6     54.4          pose = Pose()
    26     10000    1573284.0    157.3      6.6          pose.position.x = 0
    27     10000    1304890.0    130.5      5.5          pose.position.y = 0
    28     10000    1533402.0    153.3      6.5          pose.position.z = 0
    29     10000    1412335.0    141.2      5.9          pose.orientation.x = 0
    30     10000    1374551.0    137.5      5.8          pose.orientation.y = 0
    31     10000    1363287.0    136.3      5.7          pose.orientation.z = 0
    32     10000    1222556.0    122.3      5.1          pose.orientation.w = 0

I'm curious why this is happening and if there is a way around the issue, either in  how I define or how I fill my messages.

what are you trying to achieve by creating so many messages in one go ?

I'm not exactly sure I understand the question. I use the messages in downstream processes. They are generated from a node in a single process, so that's why they get generated/published in one go.

it sounds to me that you are generating all your message once instead of having your process run and the message being generated during the execution time. For logging messages over a period of time there exist rosbag that you can replay. Otherwise generating 10k msg and processing them as part as your flow will always be time intensive

My messages are being generated at runtime, the messages are the result of a single forward pass through a grasp generation network. But that seems a bit beside the point because I can write a python dataclass that has the same structure that is generated and filled several times faster. My question is specifically if there is anything inherent in ROS to explain the difference.

Ok I got it, and then you have also have some publisher for your graps.msg ? Usually dataserialization at the publisher as some overhead. https://answers.ros.org/question/238920/performance-cost-of-rostopic/ and https://answers.ros.org/question/259608/ros-publish-taking-more-time-than-expected/

No, the overhead is incurred at message generation. See my code in the comment. Simply creating the messages takes a lot of time, more time than an equivalent python dataclass would take.
